# JNA call to C function

Tags: java, c, jna

I have a function in C GetProductString( DWORD DeviceNum,LPVOID DeviceString, DWORD Options). How do I call this in [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna/)?

Comment: What have you tried?  Also, for some reason the text of your question is showing a problem, the symbol right before the LPVOID word shows a question mark in a box.

Answer (score 0):

If you're having trouble mapping `LPVOID`, it's most likely a `char*` or a `wchar*`. You're also missing the return value type, so look into getting the complete function signature.

Need more information to help further.

Comment: these are the parameters return types 1.DeviceNum—Index of the device for which the product description string, serial number, or full
path is desired.
2.DeviceString—Variable of type CP210x_DEVICE_STRING returning the NULL-terminated serial number, device description or full path string.
3.Options—Flag that determines if DeviceString contains the product description, serial number, or full-path string.

Comment: I really don't think JNA cares about your parameters' description, only about the actual function signature.